# How to extract value JSON data from the Table?

Tags: sql

I have a table named "UNKNOWN":

```
ID ToF Value
1   T  {"Noisy": Yes, "Ugly": Yes, "Pretty": No)
2   F  {"Noisy": Yes, "Ugly": No, "Pretty": No)
3   T  {"Noisy": Yes, "Ugly": Yes, "Pretty": No)
4   F  {"Noisy": No, "Ugly": Yes, "Pretty": No)
5   F  {"Noisy": Yes, "Ugly": Yes, "Pretty": Yes)
6   T  {"Noisy": Yes, "Ugly": Yes, "Stupid": No)
```

I'm trying to extract the Value, so I used: `SELECT * FROM UNKOWN WHERE CONTAINS(Value, 'Stupid)` to extract the Value that contains the word, Stupid. But it's not returning anything. Is it possible to extract the value?

Comment: What database system is being used? Basically in SQL it would be `SELECT * FROM UNKNOWN WHERE Value LIKE '%Stupid%';`. Based on whether the column `Value` can store (and interpret) JSON data, the query could be enhanced to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `SELECT * FROM UNKOWN WHERE Value LIKE '%Stupid%'`
The `%`'s are wildcards, meaning any text can be left or right of `'Stupid'`.

Comment: It says 0 rows returned. It's trying to find it, but I guess it can't recognize the string? Is it different for JSON I wonder

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Value` column has type `JSON` (or an equivalent), the answer depends on your database.

In Postgres, you [should use the ? operator:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNKNOWN WHERE Value ? 'Stupid'
```

For MySQL you should [use JSON_CONTAINS_PATH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html):

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNKNOWN WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Value, "all", '$.Stupid')
```